# Syntax or Variable error in PHP

Tags: php, variables, syntax

Is there any problem with this PHP code? It displays nothing. Please help.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$device = Detect::deviceType();
$device_brand = Detect::brand();
$operating_system = Detect::os();
$browser_name = Detect::browser();
$service_host = Detect::ipHostname();
$service_org = Detect::ipOrg();
$ip_country = Detect::ipCountry();
echo $host;
echo $date_time;
echo "IP: ". $ip_country;
?>
```

Comment: where does the Detect:: come from?

Comment: Probably one of two things: 1) The `Detect` class terminates the script without any messages, or 2) the script fails but you have errors turned off.

Comment: Make sure you have had Detect class.

Comment: How to add detect class? Sorry, i am not PHP expert.

Comment: Got it, solved after I add "require_once 'detect/detect.php';". Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your script is calling Detect class, but I don't see from where it comes. Are you including a file containing its declaration?

2) Is Detect class "mute", ie, works without verbose response?

3) If you are not getting any errors, try to add to your script first lines

`error_reporting(2047); 
ini_set("display_errors",1);`

Comment: How to add detect class? Sorry, i am not PHP expert.

Comment: Look for "class Detect" in the same document, or if you are using include, require, etc, it should be somewhere in the included files. Without a class declaration, you can't use it :)

Comment: Got it, solved after I add "require_once 'detect/detect.php';". Thank you guys.